# How to compile multiple python scripts to exe python 3.5

Tags: python

I have 7 scripts that all call eachother at some point, so I want to compile them all and have it as a single .exe that I can run anywhere. Pyinstaller isn't working for me, it keeps coming up with errors such as `WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-won-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python35\DLLs\_ssl.pyd`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to compile your scripts to an .exe is [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). Or like creyD said Pyinstaller.

Comment: I'm using cx_Freeze right now! To compile multiple scripts can I just make `executables = [Executable("distme.py")]` in `setup` into `executables = [Executable("distme.py"), Executable("distme2.py")]` or `executables = [Executable("distme.py", "distme2.py")]`?

Comment: `executables = [Executable("")]` is correct I think.

Comment: no, I mean, how could I make multiple python files in to one exe?

Comment: Ahh okay sry. So to do this you can easily use `Packages =` in your setup.py. So for example: Packages = ["example1", "example2", "example3"]

Comment: Thanks, what about if I have an Assets file (since I'm using PyQt5), do I have to do anything special with that or can I just drop it in the folder when I've compiled it?

Comment: Hmm I have no experience with PyQt5. I guess the best way to see if this is working, is to test it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use another program (like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or similar)? If this doesn´t help  and you can´t merge them into one larger script (what would be my prefered way) maybe you could should check on the dll Pyinstaller can´t find, cause it seems like one of your scripts would need it.

If you need to include the dll file into your exe maybe [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency) will help you...